# Disallow record updates for a given type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, record

Let's say I have some types:

```hs
data Person = Person
  { worksFor :: String
  , ...
  }

data Company = Company
  { companyId :: String
  , address :: String
  ,...
  }

companies :: [Company]
people :: [Person]
```

`worksFor` in `Person` references a given `Company` by way of `companyId`. Let's then say I tie the knot and end up with:

```hs
data Person' = Person'
  { worksFor :: Company'
  , ...
  }

data Company' = Company'
  { ...
  }
```

Obviously, multiple `Person`s can reference the same `Company`, but in `Person'` this sharing is lost. Also obviously, if I update a given `Company'` this update will not be reflected in the values of type `Person'` that reference that `Company'`.

I'm aware of `IxSet` and the like, but I would prefer to keep it simple. I'd like to disallow any kind of record updates of the `Person'` and `Company'` records, while still being able to access their fields.

One solution would be to define `Company'` and `Person'` in a separate module with `NoTraditionalRecordSyntax` allowed (and thus defining the datatypes without record syntax, e.g. `data Company' = Company' String String ...`), define selector functions mimicking the field selectors generated by GHC, and not export any constructors, but that seems like overkill.

Another one would be to wrap every field in the `...'` data types with e.g. `data Gettable a = Gettable { get :: a }` and not export the `Gettable` constructor, but then every field access must be preceded with `get`, which is pretty ugly.

I'm wondering if there's another way to achieve this which I'm not seeing?

Comment: Don't export constructors and write the getters manually.

Comment: Notice also that the structure in this specific problem is a _bipartite graph_, so it might make sense to not do any custom knot-tying but instead use a library implementation like [`Algebra.Graph.Bipartite`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/algebraic-graphs-0.7/docs/Algebra-Graph-Bipartite-AdjacencyMap.html). Or simpler, not store `worksFor` as a field for `Person` at all but instead infer that from the company that employs this person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One solution would be to define `Company'` and `Person'` in a separate module with `NoTraditionalRecordSyntax` allowed (and thus defining the datatypes without record syntax, e.g. `data Company' = Company' String String ...`), define selector functions mimicking the field selectors generated by GHC, and not export any constructors, but that seems like overkill.

This sounds exactly right to me. The purpose of record syntax is to declare that your type is just a boring concrete tuple type, with any values allowed for all of its fields. You don't want this; you want an abstract type with access controls. So, don't use a record, don't export the constructor, and define selector functions by hand. A bit of a hassle, but sometimes that's the price of the right API.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: As noted in the comments, the below recommendation *does not* prevent record syntax updates like `p { worksFor = "foo" }`.

---

The most straightforward way to disallow field updates is to not export their constructors. You can still write them as records and export the field names as getters by listing the field names separately in the export list.

You will likely need to have *some* way to construct them outside the module they're defined in, in which case you can define your own constructor and export that (could be as simple as `mkPerson = Person`).

See for example [this article](https://www.haskellforall.com/2020/07/record-constructors.html?m=1) that uses a similar approach.

Comment: The problem is that even if you don't export the constructors but already have a value `c :: Company'` you can still do a record update `c { address = "..." }`.

Comment: Ah, I did not realize that! My bad, updated my answer to reflect that. It seems that the approach you outlined in the question is indeed your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you want to keep the "read-only" part of the record syntax, but disallow updates, you could try to exploit pattern synonyms.

Unfortunately, it does require some boilerplate. We need to define a module and be careful in exporting only the public interface.

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

module PatSynRecord
  ( R(R)  -- the type and the pattern synonym
  , a     -- the patsyn fields (it would be nice if we didn't have to list them)
  , b
  , c
  , test  -- an example
  ) where

-- The private, internal representation
data R = PriR
  { priA :: Int
  , priB :: String
  , priC :: Bool
  }
  deriving Show

-- Optional type signature
pattern R :: Int -> String -> Bool -> R
pattern R { a, b, c } <- PriR {priA=a, priB=b, priC=c}
{-# COMPLETE R #-}

-- In this module we can use the internal representation
test :: R
test = PriR { priA=1, priB="dsaasd", priC=True }
```

The above patsyn is a unidirectional one, so the users of this module can only use it to read data from the record. These are allowed:

```
a test + 4
case test of R{a=x} -> x+4
```

This update is not

```
test{ a=45 }
```

This solution is not ideal since the fields must be repeated in the `PriR` private constructor, in the `R` public patsyn (twice!), and in the module export list. On the positive side, using a module like this allows to export the wanted smart constructors, only, effectively constraining the values of type `R` that can be created.